# Installing problem with spring-tool-suite

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I use Eclipse and Spring Tool Suite.

Today I was trying to start spring-tool-suite, but there was a problem. The link to "sts-something-.exe" was missing.

I didn't move anything. I removed Eclipse and Spring Tool Suite from my laptop, then I redownloaded Eclipse, and then Spring Tool Suite.

Eclipse works.

Then I tried to download spring-tool-suite.
I download the jar, and with double click it should install itself, but when I double-click, it opens the terminal of windows and then disappears in one second.

Error:

```
Error: could not find or load main class C:\Users\Peppe\Downloads\spring-tool-suite  
-4-4.7.0.RELEASE-e4.16.0-win32.win32.x86-64.self-extracting.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : C:\Users\Peppe\Downloads\spring-tool-suite
-4-4.7.0.RELEASE-e4.16.0-win32.win32.x86-64.self-extracting.jar
```

Maybe I need to delete some data from the older version I had? Is there some sort of cache that I need to delete? Where can I find it?

Comment: I tried the same on my Windows machine (using JDK11 and Spring Tools for Eclipse 4.7.0), but it seems to work just fine. Maybe something went wrong while downloading the STS 4.7.0 for Windows JAR file?

Comment: @MartinLippert thx for your answer.
No, i tried to download the jar many times, nothing changed.
may be a problem with path variable? or classpath variable of my system?
do u know what settings are needed on those variables?

Comment: what happens if you execute `java -jar <stsjarfile>` ?